# jQuery Cookie causing Disallowed Key Characters in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I'm using the jQuery Tabs UI along with the jQuery Cookie plugin from GitHub. My problem is that using it is causing me to have a Disallowed Key Characters error once the cookie is stored. I tweaked the Input file in the CI Core and it tells me that it doesn't like the words object Object in the name. The name of the cookie is "ui-tabs-[object Object]" which seems to be the problem.

Anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the default name used by UI tab for the cookie. The default name is something like ui-tabs-[object Object]. If you specifically set the name of the cookie to something without braces, it fixes the problem. Following fixed the problem in my case:

```
$("#stuff").tabs({
  cookie: { name: 'mycookie' }
});
```

Hope it helps in some way

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much! this little bug has caused me problems for a week to the point I swapped out my authorization library. Oh well. thank you for the quick answer, I appreciate it! :)